# Do contour plots over first two principal components reveal local convexity/concavity?

Tags: pca, convex, non-convex

When I plot a contour plot of a variable over two principal components I can see what appears to be hills and valleys. But I also know I am only looking at the contours over a projection.

Here is a quick self-contained example.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)

plt.tricontourf(
*PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X).T, 
y, 
cmap='terrain',
levels=100
)

plt.xlabel('PC1')
plt.ylabel('PC2')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I see hills and valleys on the contour plot, does that entail there exists locally convex/concave regions over the original space?

---

If it helps, here is a quick 3D surface for the same contour plot:

[image]

---

[`plt.tricontourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) produces a colour-filled [contour plot](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/contour.htm) based on a triangular tesselation computed from the data. The boundaries between levels are interpolated [level sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set).

A link to further documentation and references on the diabetes dataset can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/toy_dataset.html#diabetes-dataset). My question isn't special to this dataset, but rather is just an example of the plotting procedure. Many other data sets are suitable *mutatis mutandis*.

---

The local minima shown in `import numpy as np; from sklearn.decomposition import PCA; np.random.seed(100); X = np.random.normal(size=100*3).reshape(100,3); Q = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X); plt.tricontourf(*Q.T, X[:,2]);plt.show()` convinces me that the 2D projection can still be misleading about convexity.

[image]

Sampling error is sufficient for demotivating my intuition.

Comment: I am mystified by your plot because everything depends on understanding what the function `plt.tricontourf` might be doing.  Could you please explain?  When you do, it would also help to describe the dataset you use.

Comment: Please: without a clear description of the data, it's impossible to understand what this plot is trying to show.  Telling us that it is contouring the data is merely stating the obvious without providing any useful information.